# Event dispatched on filter applied in Product Listing/Category View page

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I have a module where I want to send data to an API whenever any filter is applied on the product listing/category view page (list or grid). The data being sent should contain only the latest filter applied, not all the filters.

I can write the rest of the logic in an observer but I can't seem to find any event which is dispatched whenever a filter is applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
catalog_block_product_list_collection 
catalog_product_collection_load_before
catalog_product_collection_load_after
```

I think you can use above events for your purpose

when you initially load on listing page you get `$_GET` null array

and if some filter is there then you will get some value

Comment: @JayGhosh you are always welcome

Answer (score -1):

Can try log all Events to file-log -

https://mage2.pro/t/topic/3718

Comment: Unrelated and not useful